# Mysql Correlated Subquery vs Join performance

Tags: mysql

I've always thought that Joins were faster than Subqueries. However for a very simple query in a small dataset the Join is returning in 1.0s whereas the Correlated-Subquery returns in 0.001s. Seems like something is wrong. I note that both queries are using the correct (appallingly named) indexes. Over 1 sec seems excessive for the Join. Any ideas?

Please compare these two queries with their Explain plans:

a) Using a Join

```
select user.id, user.username, 
count(distinct bet_placed.id) as bets_placed,
count(distinct bet_won.id) as bets_won,
count(distinct bets_involved.id) as bets_involved
from user 
left join bet as bet_placed on bet_placed.user_placed = user.id 
left join bet as bet_won on bet_won.user_won = user.id 
left join bet_accepters as bets_involved on bets_involved.user = user.id 
group by user.id
```

Explain plan:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  user    index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   NULL    86  100.00  NULL
1   SIMPLE  bet_placed  ref fk_bet_user1_idx    fk_bet_user1_idx    4   xxx.user.id 6   100.00  "Using index"
1   SIMPLE  bet_won ref user_won_idx    user_won_idx    5   xxx.user.id 8   100.00  "Using index"
1   SIMPLE  bets_involved   ref FK_user_idx FK_user_idx 4   xxx.user.id 8   100.00  "Using index"
```

Average response time: 1.0 secs

b) Using a Correlated-Subquery

```
select user.id, user.username, 
(select COALESCE(count(bet.id), 0) from bet where bet.user_placed = user.id) as bets_placed,
(select COALESCE(count(bet.id), 0) from bet where bet.user_won = user.id) as bets_won,
(select COALESCE(count(bet_accepters.id), 0) from bet_accepters where bet_accepters.user = user.id) as bets_involved
from user;
```

Explain plan:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY user    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    86  100.00  NULL
4   "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY"    bet_accepters   ref FK_user_idx FK_user_idx 4   xxx.user.id 8   100.00  "Using index"
3   "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY"    bet ref user_won_idx    user_won_idx    5   xxx.user.id 8   100.00  "Using index"
2   "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY"    bet ref fk_bet_user1_idx    fk_bet_user1_idx    4   xxx.user.id 6   100.00  "Using index"
```

Average response time: 0.001 secs

Answer (score 2):

Please see

---

[image]

which shows a comparison in speed/rows for different types of query.

It may be that there is little/no difference (either way) on 'smaller' datasets (but may ary on way the db has been set up, as well as the DBMS used), but as you can see,

However, in relation to other 'query types', these are much faster than other operations (shown below):

[image]

---

> **Subquery vs. Join**
>
> Both the subquery and join solutions perform reasonably well when very
>   small partitions are involved (up to several hundred rows per
>   partition). As partition size grows, the performance of these
>   solutions degrades in a quadratic (N2) manner, becoming quite poor.
>   But as long as the partitions are small, performance degradation
>   caused by an increase in number of partitions is linear. One factor
>   that might affect your choice between using a subquery-based or
>   join-based solution is the number of aggregates requested. As I
>   discussed, the subquery-based approach requires a separate scan of the
>   data for each aggregate, whereas the join-based approach doesn’t—so
>   you’ll most likely want to use the join approach when you need to
>   calculate multiple aggregates.

~[SOURCE](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/subqueries-and-joins-running-aggregates)

Comment: Interesting however I wonder if there is a difference here due to the fact that all of that information is based on SQLServer and I am using MySQL. Very different engines.